# Partial sums $1+(x+2/x)+(3x+2/x)+(5x+2/x)+(7x+2/x)+\ldots$ are all squares. What would be the value of $x$?

Tags: number-theory

Find all $x$ such that all partial sums of the series: $$1+(x+2/x)+(3x+2/x)+(5x+2/x)+(7x+2/x)+\ldots$$ are square numbers (i.e. squares of some integers).

---

I know that $x=1$ is a solution, but I have not managed to find any other solutions, and I have also failed to prove that $x=1$ is the only solution.

---

In fact, the solution of $1$ for the series has urged me to do some deductions which is like this,

If we put $x=1$, then the summation becomes,

$1+3+5+7+9+……….=z^2$

& we know that summation of all odd numbers will result in a perfect square at any point of summation for some positive integers $z$.

Now, we can rewrite the series also in this way,

$1+(x+3x+5x+7x+9x+………)+(2/x+2/x+2/x+2/x+2/x+…….)=z^2$

or,$1+x(1+3+5+7+9+………)+2(1/x+1/x+1/x+1/x+1/x+1/x+……..)=z^2$

or,$1+x(z^2)+2(1/x+1/x+1/x+1/x+1/x+………..)=z^2$

or,$z^2(x-1)+2(1/x+1/x+1/x+1/x+…..)=-1$

Now if we put $x=1$, then

$(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+…………..)=-1/2$

i.e. if we add up $1$ to infinity the result would be $(-1/2)$!!

It’s as good as saying that the sum of positive natural numbers up to infinity is $(-1/2)$!!.

Comment: What does the ellipsis here (.....) mean? Is this an infinite sum? If yes, I struggle to see how it can be convergent for *any* $x$. If not, then *how many terms does it have*? $n$? (Counting the initial $1$ or not?) Also, if it is a finite sum, **hint**: use the identity $1+3+5+7+\ldots+(2k-1)=k^2$ to simplify it.

Comment: The sum is up to infinite terms, counting the initial term $1$.

Comment: Then there is no such $x$. Note that, for a series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ to converge, the term $a_k$ must converge to zero when $k\to\infty$. However, you cannot have $\lim_{k\to\infty}(2k+1)x+2/x$ to be zero for any $x$: this limit is $+\infty$ if $x>0$, $-\infty$ if $x<0$, and due to $x$ being in the denominator, $x$ cannot be $0$ either!

Comment: Thus, I think it is more likely that *there is a finite number of terms* (most probably $n$) - can you please go to the original statement of the problem and check?

Comment: There is such $x$ and the series is up to infinite terms counting the initial term $1$ such that the series will always produce a square at any point of summation for some positive integer values of $n$.

Comment: If *that* is what you want to say in your question, why didn't you say so? For example: "Find all real $x$ such that all partial sums of the series: $1+(x+2/x)+(3+2/x)+(5+2/x)+\ldots$ are square integers..." or something like that. This will still leave the question unmotivated, without any signs of your own attempt etc. (see: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask - so it would probably still be closed), but at least it will be clearer what you are asking in the first place!

Comment: And, my hint above still applies. Plus, it looks like $x=1$ is a solution, so probably the problem is to prove that no other numbers are solutions.

Comment: Yes. That's why I asked about the problem.  In fact, I know $x=1$ is one of the solutions but I don't know if there is or are other solutions or not or how to prove this.

Comment: I've tried to edit the question so that it is more suitable to this site. Hope it will attract enough "reopen" votes. I have not looked if this may be a duplicate of another question on MSE - you may want to search as well.

Comment: Hint: all the partial sums must be integers. So the difference between two consecutive partial sums must be an integer. So the difference of these differences must be an integer too. Therefore...

Answer (score 0):

I know that $x=1$ is a solution, but I have not managed to find any other solutions, and I have also failed to prove that $x=1$ is the only solution.

---

In fact, the solution as $x=1$ for the series has urged me to do some deductions which is like this,

If we put $x=1$, then the summation becomes,

$1+3+5+7+9+……….=z^2$

& we know that summation of all odd numbers will result in a perfect square at any point of summation for some positive integers $z$.

Now, we can rewrite the series also in this way,

$1+(x+3x+5x+7x+9x+………)+(2/x+2/x+2/x+2/x+2/x+…….)=z^2$

or,$1+x(1+3+5+7+9+………)+2(1/x+1/x+1/x+1/x+1/x+1/x+……..)=z^2$

or,$1+x(z^2)+2(1/x+1/x+1/x+1/x+1/x+………..)=z^2$

or,$z^2(x-1)+2(1/x+1/x+1/x+1/x+…..)=-1$

Now if we put $x=1$, then

$(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+…………..)=-1/2$

i.e. if we add up $1$ to infinity the result would be $(-1/2)$!!

It’s as good as saying that the sum of positive natural numbers up to infinity is $(-1/2)$!!.

Note: This deduction holds for infinite terms but not for finite terms.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).